# Codeigniter: send all requests that do not match a controller's name to the default controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-url

I'm working on a project involving two kinds of URLs, one following the standard CI pattern

```
http://fancysite.com/controller/
```

And another presenting the following scheme:

```
http://fancysite.com/category
```

I would like the second to call the default controller's `handlecategory` (or something like that) function with `category` as an argument.

Bonus love if you could also tell me how to let URLs like http://place.fancysite.com/ call the same function passing just `place` as an argument if no category follows that URL, or both `place` and `category` if it does.

Additional datum: I already know the names of all controllers, places, categories.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102025/#514638 might answer your subdomain query ~

Comment: @Ross thanks! actually, I think I can derive the rest of what i need from that example. i will post the full solution tomorrow, after testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the codeigniter's [URI routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for achieving this -

**Insert this at the end of your route file -**

```
$route[':any'] = 'path of the default controller';
```

**All the other routes should be placed above the upper code.**

Lets say the URL codeigniter encountered is -

http://fancysite.com/category

So firstly codeigniter will search if there is a controller named category.
if it does not get that then it will check the route file to check that is there 
any route specified like this -

```
$route['category/:any'] = 'actual path';
```

If there is no such route specified in that case codeigniter will pass this
request to path of the default controller you have mentioned in your last line
of routes.

Even if the link contains sub-domain it doesn't matter the request will go to
same default controller.

Now you can insert logic for sub-domain handling or anything else
in the default controller.

You can even obtain the parameter **'category' in our url example taken** which is 
in the URL using codeigniters [URI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) helper class as below -

```
$this->uri->segment(1);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I have to admit that I was pretty lazy and should have carefully read the docs before asking. Could you please integrate @Ross comment in your answer, for the sake of completeness?