# Codeigniter rerouting doesnt except controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hy i'm trying to do the same as was written in that question:
[Codeigniter: send all requests that do not match a controller's name to the default controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507676/codeigniter-send-all-requests-that-do-not-match-a-controllers-name-to-the-defa). So i'm trying to call a function when id doesn't match a controler name. So here is what i have done in confgi/routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['page/privacy-policy'] = "pages/privacyPolicy";
$route['u/(:any)'] = "profile/show/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "login/show/$1";
```

So if i go to url

```
mypage.com/myname
```

it goes to login/show which is fine, but problem is that if i type in

```
mypage.com/main
```

and it stils goes to the login/show. Any ideas how to owerride that behaviour?

And if i type in

```
mypage.com
```

it also goes to the login/show.

Comment: With this route (:any) you match all routes no matter default_controller only page/privacy-policy and u/$ will be accessible because they are before this route. When you write different url from this 2 its matched as :any .. and you go to that login page..

Comment: So how would i do that when i write thing that is same as controller name would go to the controller name and not to login. I want people to be redirect to login only when they insert some data that doesn't make sense in form mypage.com/nonsence

Comment: You mean the not existing page which is 404 page... "404_override" 
You can set it to some controller for example Main with method Not_existsing and from there to redirect user to that login page :)

Comment: Yea but i dont want to redirect when link is like mypage.com/main/nonsence, so that one wont work for me ... Basicly i wont seperated functions for 404-override and that example.

Comment: $route['404_override'] = "login/show";
 Then directly set this login/show to 404 override .. if you need to use something from the url use Codeigniter route segments

Comment: How do i send parameter with that? I want to know what user inserted. and like i said i want diffrent methods for mypage.com/nonsence and mypage.com/main/nonsence. Ow isee that could work!

Comment: My last answer to you :) http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html in your login show with this CI library function you can access current url segments (/segment1/segment2/..) and to set cases if segment1==main do something...  Good luck ;)

Comment: Yes u were very help full, thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think `$route['(:any)']` will match any set of URI requests.
If you want all your controllers to be secure you must Extend them from a SecureController and set the login verification check in that SecureController's constructor.

Comment: No that's not what i intend to do here, I don't want controllers to be secure so that's not the deal.

Comment: Because if people insert mypage.com/some random nonsence i want them to be redirected to login, however if they insert mypage.com/main/some random nonsence i dont want to redirect them. Thanks for help!